# row with minimum value of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having this selection:

```
id IDSLOT  N_UM
------------------------
1  1  6
2  6  2
3  2  1
4  4  1
5  5  1
6  8  1
7  3  1
8  7  1
9  9  1
10  10  0
```

I would like to get the row (only one) which has the minimun value of N_UM, in this case the row with id=10 (10 0).

Comment: For the sake of completeness, what behavior do you expect if you have multiple rows with the same minimum value? Would you want to return all rows that match? Return the single row with the largest ID? Smallest ID? Either one?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this -

```
 select top 1 * from table where N_UM = (select min(N_UM) from table);
```

Comment: plus, he only wanted one row.

Comment: + `Limit 1` if you only want 1 row (like asked).

Comment: Agreed, agreed - Edited my answer to satisfy all comments.

Comment: Still, Adam V and my variant is more pure: one select, no filtering.

Comment: Shouldn't Andrejs Cainikovs' solution is faster way compare to double select?

Answer (score 28):

```
select * from TABLE_NAME order by COLUMN_NAME limit 1
```

Comment: Don't you mean `order by N_UM`?

Comment: This is a generic example. Substitute the table and column names with whatever you need.

Comment: This is excellent. Not all DB's support "TOP" and I was getting syntax errors on all the other suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Very elegant. Similarly, if someone needs max then ```select * from TABLE_NAME order by COLUMN_NAME desc limit 1```

Comment: The question is tagged sql-server. SQL Server does not support the `limit` keyword

Answer (score 18):

I'd try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM TABLE1
ORDER BY N_UM
```

(using SQL Server)

Comment: +1 Beat me by 4 seconds. We need to know RDBMS though as might be `limit` or something else.

Comment: @Martin Smith: true true. I use SQL Server, so I just answered it that way. Should probably mark it as such. :)

Answer (score 6):

Use this sql query:

```
select id,IDSLOT,N_UM from table where N_UM = (select min(N_UM) from table));
```

Comment: Why `in` rather than `=`? This can cause performance issues in MySQL.

Comment: Wrong : 1. will return multiple rows, 2. two selects for such a simple task is not an option

Answer (score 6):

Method 1:

```
SELECT top 1 * 
FROM table 
WHERE N_UM = (SELECT min(N_UM) FROM table);
```

Method 2:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
ORDER BY N_UM 
LIMIT 1
```

A more general solution to this class of problem is as follows.

Method 3:

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE N_UM IN (SELECT MIN(N_UM) FROM table);
```

Comment: which one is faster? I guess method #2?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach

```
Create table #t (
id int,
IDSLOT int,
N_UM int
)
insert into #t ( id, idslot, n_um )
VALUES (1, 1, 6),
 (2,6,2),
 (3,2,1),
 (4,4,1),
 (5,5,1),
 (6,8,1),
 (7,3,1),
 (8,7,1),
 (9,9,1),
 (10, 10, 0)

 select Top 1 *
 from #t
 Where N_UM = ( select MIN(n_um) from #t )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select TOP 1  Col , COUNT(Col) as minCol from employee GROUP by Col
order by mindep  asc
```