# Select query to return only the min datetime without group by?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatetime

My table displays as below,

```
|_______________|____________|_____________________|______________________|
|  ENTRY POINT  |    NAME    |    DATE OF ENTRY    |   DATETIME OF ENTRY  | 
|_______________|____________|_____________________|______________________|
|    CHECKIN    |  CHOCOTACO |     05/07/2018      | 05/07/2018 00:01:00  | 
|_______________|____________|_____________________|______________________|
|    CHECKIN 1  |  CHOCOTACO |     05/07/2018      | 05/07/2018 00:01:10  | 
|_______________|____________|_____________________|______________________|
|    CHECKIN 2  |  CHOCOTACO |     05/07/2018      | 05/07/2018 00:01:15  | 
|_______________|____________|_____________________|______________________|
|    CHECKIN 10 |  CHOCOTACO |     06/07/2018      | 06/07/2018 00:07:10  | 
|_______________|____________|_____________________|______________________|
|    CHECKIN 4  |  CHOCOTACO |     06/07/2018      | 06/07/2018 00:07:10  | 
|_______________|____________|_____________________|______________________|
|    CHECKIN 5  |  CHOCOTACO |     06/07/2018      | 06/07/2018 00:09:15  | 
|_______________|____________|_____________________|______________________|
```

Output expected is only the first value which has the min DATETIME OF ENTRY for each day as below,

```
|_______________|____________|_____________________|______________________|
|  ENTRY POINT  |    NAME    |    DATE OF ENTRY    |   DATETIME OF ENTRY  | 
|_______________|____________|_____________________|______________________|
|    CHECKIN    |  CHOCOTACO |     05/07/2018      | 05/07/2018 00:01:00  | 
|_______________|____________|_____________________|______________________|
|    CHECKIN 10 |  CHOCOTACO |     06/07/2018      | 06/07/2018 00:07:10  | 
|_______________|____________|_____________________|______________________|
```

If I try to take the min DATETIME OF ENTRY, it probably makes me use a `group by` 'ENTRY POINT' and other column which basically gives me the same output as my input.

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: what kind of sql are you using? sql server, MySql etc.?

Comment: See answers to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839982/row-with-minimum-value-of-a-column

Comment: i am using sql server

Comment: this link shows how to return first row, but i need my query to return first datetime of entry for each day. irrespective of entry point https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839982/row-with-minimum-value-of-a-column,

Comment: cant you just group by Name and Date of Entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need window analytic functions of which `DENSE_RANK()` would suit well to include all ties(*the records with the same `[DATETIME OF ENTRY]` values per each `[NAME]` and `[DATE OF ENTRY]` combination*).

Need to find out the first record(s) of ascendingly ordered `[DATETIME OF ENTRY]` value grouped (partitioned) by each `[NAME]` and `[DATE OF ENTRY]` :

```
SELECT [ENTRY POINT], [NAME], [DATE OF ENTRY], [DATETIME OF ENTRY]
  FROM
 (
  SELECT T.*,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER 
              (PARTITION BY [NAME], [DATE OF ENTRY] ORDER BY [DATETIME OF ENTRY]) AS dr
    FROM T -- <your table>
  ) TT
  WHERE dr = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window function `row_number()`. here is the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1a1e4/1).

```
select
    ENTRY_POINT,   
    NAME, 
    DATE_OF_ENTRY,   
    DATETIME_OF_ENTRY
from    
(
    select
        *,
        row_number() over (order by DATETIME_OF_ENTRY) as rnk
    from myTable
) t
where rnk = 1
```

Comment: if i try to duplicate the same data with different date, i need the query to return values for that as well. If i add a entry 06/07 1:00 and 07/07 1:00, it should return me three output like 05/07 1:00, 06/07 1:00 and 07/07 1:00

Comment: @hdhanarajan I did not get you?

Comment: the above query only returns 05/07 1:00 which basically the same answer that I will get if i use limit as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839982/row-with-minimum-value-of-a-column

Comment: @hdhanarajan did not you mention that you need only min value without using `min` ?

Comment: @hdhanarajan please update your question with expected result and cases you want to cover. also how adding different time can make your data duplicate.